# Unable to uninstall shorewall from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, firewall, software-uninstall

I noticed on some of my servers that the shorewall service is installed but it's not running. I want to uninstall it.

I executed the command `sudo systemctl status shorewall` to check the status of shorewall and got the below output.

```
shorewall.service - Shorewall IPv4 firewall
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/shorewall.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Then I executed `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove shorewall` command to uninstall the shorewall package. After uninstalling it, I checked the status of shorewall with this command again `sudo systemctl status shorewall`, which shows output this:

```
shorewall.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
Jul 08 20:24:23 ip-10-10-10-10 systemd[1]: Stopped Shorewall IPv4 firewall.
```

Can anyone confirm please that shorewall was uninstalled successfully? Why is it giving output like this?

Comment: What is "ubuntu 16"?

Comment: what happens if you run `sudo systemctl stop shorewall.service` or `sudo systemctl disable shorewall.service`

Comment: @Nmath -  ```sudo systemctl stop shorewall.service``` doesn't show anything on prompt. After running ```stop``` command then I checked the ```status``` it is showing the same output as it showing after removing it which is mentioned in question. ```sudo systemctl disable shorewall.service``` is showing this output ```Unknown operation disabled```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem. You've uninstalled the service, and it is not running.

The journal is showing the moment when it was stopped.

So what is your concern?

Comment: If shorewall is uninstalled completely then status command ```sudo systemctl status shorewall``` should show the output something like ```shorewall is not found``` or ```shorewall services is unknown```.

Comment: This is exactly what it is showing. But it is showing that it used to run before.